# SQL WHERE matching statement (not LIKE)

Tags: sql, match

I'm struggling with this problem since couple of weeks but I can't find a solution for that.

I'm making an example to make it clear: let's suppose we have this table (`FILTER_TABLE`):

| ID | Filter |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | foo* |
| 2 | *bar |
| 3 | * |

I would find a way to make a SQL query so that I can select row with ID 1 for all the strings that match the pattern foo*, 2 for *bar and 3 for everything.

In pseudo-SQL:

```
SELECT ID 
FROM FILTER_TABLE 
WHERE FILTER MATCHES "fooString"
```

It should return 1.

I know that the `MATCHES` condition doesn't exist, unfortunately. But this is what I would like to have. My SQL knowledge is quite limited, but as far as I can see there's no way to get what I want.

Do you have any hint?

Comment: And why is it not `LIKE` (with additional steps)? `where REPLACE( filter, '*', '%') like my_table.some_other_column`. Or am I missing something here?

Comment: What has to be returned when fooString is 'foobar' ? It matches every line of your example. And have fooString and filter any chance to contain '%' ?

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Answer (score 2):

You don't specify which implementation of SQL you are using, but in T-SQL you can use a `REPLACE` statement to use the SQL wildcard character `%`:

```
SELECT ID 
FROM   FILTER_TABLE 
WHERE  "fooString" LIKE REPLACE(FILTER, '*', '%')
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer.
I've always thought that you can use LIKE statement to match the content of a field to a pattern, not the other way around.
I've learned something new, thanks.